# GridView with different count of widgets per row

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

I want to make kind of a grid view but in a way that the amount of widgets per row is determined by the width of widgets(my widgets have different width). I have surfed the web, but it does not give me anything. So, what shall I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to use a [`Wrap`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html)

It puts its children horizontally as much as fits and wrapping to a new row as much as needed